# Is pg_stat_statements available on heroku free and hobby tiers

Tags: heroku-postgres

Is `pg_stat_statements` available on heroku free and hobby tiers? If so, how do you enable it?

At present, if I go `heroku pg:psql --production` and type the following

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE=> SELECT queryid, calls, mean_time, substring(query for 100)
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE-> FROM pg_stat_statements
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE-> ORDER BY total_time DESC
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE-> LIMIT 10;
```

I see

```
ERROR:  relation "pg_stat_statements" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM pg_stat_statements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not installed by default but I've just checked and you can presently install it manually. Try running `create extension pg_stat_statements;` in a psql console.

Just as a heads up, due to the permission model for the basic plans, you'll see a lot of noise from other databases in the cluster that you don't have access to.